# How to change the position of a tooltip div in leaflet marker on dragging the map

Tags: leaflet

I have some markers in the leaflet map. On clicking a marker a tooltip div appears to show a chart and some information. If after that I drag the map the tooltip window remains in the same position but the markers position is changed.
I am using the following function to change the marker position

```
        function update() {

        markers.attr("transform", function(d) {             
            if(d.code==clickedcode)
                {
                console.log((map.latLngToLayerPoint([ d.lat, d.lon ]).x) + "px , "+(map.latLngToLayerPoint([ d.lat, d.lon ]).y - 80) + "px");

                div.style["left"]=(map.latLngToLayerPoint([ d.lat, d.lon ]).x) + "px";
                div.style["top"]=(map.latLngToLayerPoint([ d.lat, d.lon ]).y - 80) + "px";
                }
            return "translate("
                    + map.latLngToLayerPoint([ d.lat, d.lon ]).x + ","
                    + map.latLngToLayerPoint([ d.lat, d.lon ]).y + ")";
        });


    }
```

I am also trying to change the div position. But its not changed. How can I change the div position along with the change of position of map due to dragging.